# How to get index data from object used in v-for in select

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component involving a select element. Below, opts is an array of objects.

```
Vue.component('atcf-select', {
    props: [
        'opts',
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            element_index: '',
        };
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <select @change="onChange(opt,index)">
                <option v-for="(opt,index) in opts">
                    {{ opt.text }} {{opt.index}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        onChange(opt,index) {
            //Do something with opt and index...
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is obviously I cannot get the selected opt object and its index, and use it as a parameter for onChange method. What is the correct way to get the selected option's index and object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to pass the `opt` or `index` values to the `change` listener on the `select` element because it is outside the scope of the `v-for`.

If you don't specify any parameters for the `onChange` handler, Vue will implicitly pass an event object. From there, you can get the `selectedIndex` value via `e.target.selectedIndex`.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      opts: [
        { value: 'a', text: 'A' },
        { value: 'b', text: 'B' },
        { value: 'c', text: 'C' },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      let index = e.target.selectedIndex;
      let option = this.opts[index];
      console.log(index, option);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select @change="onChange">
    <option v-for="(opt, index) in opts" :key="index" :value="opt.value">
      {{ opt.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems e.srcElement is not defined for Firefox. I have used e.target instead. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-model

{{ option.value }} - {{ option.text }}
                
            
            Index of {{valeureSelectionnee}} is : {{ IndexValeureSelectionnee  }}

Comment: Hi, Hicham. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider using code blocks or inline code to improve the readability of your answer.